# How can i exit the python shell to the terminal in Pycharm?

Tags: django, command-line, pycharm

For example, I wrote the code;

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python manage.py command
  File "<console>", line 1
```

`python manage.py command*` to get to the shell now I can't return back to the command line in Pycharm

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to return to the terminal

1. exit()
2. ctr + D

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl-Z plus Enter .... OR.... quit()